# Use base PDF with placeholders for packing slip

Tags: .net, pdf-generation

Is there a way to start with a PDF as a raw template and replace 'placeholders' with values? like {FirstName} and then replace that with actual values in .NET?

(This is for a shipping/fulfillment situation.)

So, could I design a packing slip as a PDF, and then replace values in it easily with .NET and show it to be printed?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a **PDF form**: It has blank fields (or ones that hold default values) that can be filled in programmatically, and then saved and/or printed.

ETA

Actually, there are a few PDF technologies that may address your needs:

- *PDF Forms* aka AcroForms are regular PDF files that can be displayed and printed like any other PDF. However, they also have fields that can be edited in a supporting viewer (such as Acrobat Viewer). AcroForms are intended to be the electronic equivalent of paper forms--rather than filling them out with a pencil, you fill them out electronically. When saved or printed, the entered data is included. Data can also be imported into the form programmatically.
- *XFA Forms* are another form technology that has been included in PDF since version 1.5. They serve a similar purpose to AcroForms, but have the advantage of being laid out dynamically. Note however that they are not as widely supported and may be deprecated in the future.
- *PDF/VT* is an ISO standard for using PDFs in VDP (variable data printing). This is the scenario of a retailer who has a catalog or flier as a PDF and needs to integrate pricing information while printing a run of 100,000.

None of these to my knowledge are supported by .NET out of the box, but third-party solutions may be available. My advice is to research these options and determine which best suits your needs.

Comment: Would this be a regular pdf file that I 'open' in .NET and replace the values? Basically this needs to work as picking/packing slips for warehouses. So, an order comes in, I use .NET to fill in the ship to, bill to, fields, etc and then show it to be printed will work?